# HTTP Error 403.14 for MVC 3 RC on Windows 2008 Data Center

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been ripping my hair out about this problem all morning. It is most obviously a problem with ASP.net 4.0 not being installed properly and I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling MVC3 and .net 4.

I've also tried the popular "aspnet_iisreg -i" method but that didn't work either.

I've gotten the app to run fine on Windows 2008 R2 Standard but just can't get it to work on Windows 2008 Data Center. (this is the Amazon AMI version, if that makes a difference)

Comment: Just a few things to check, is the App Pool it is running under set to ASP.NET 4?  Also check it is in Integrated mode as Darin suggests.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that ASP.NET is not picking the request at all. Try setting Integrated Mode for your application (in contrast to Classic Mode).